# Why augmented reality used a lot square markers instead of other shape?

Tags: computer-vision, augmented-reality, object-detection, markers

I am doing some research about augmented reality recently, and I realize that a lot AR applications are using markers to detect location. However, I found most of them are using some QR code rectangular shape markers? I am wondering why people don't choose to use Triangle or Circle shape as markers?

Answer (score 0):

Because the way how the square (not rectangle) QR code is encoded gives better recognition performances than other shapes.
In general Reed–Solomon error correction algorithm is used to decode and recognize a QR code and if you watch carefully one of those square QR codes you will probably notice that most of them have some particular pattern in common: black square dots on white background. 
Moreover, any image recognition algorithm performs much better on patterns that are somehow known beforehand: white background square with black dots, usually 3 smaller black bordered squares in the corners (except lower right), etc, etc. The result: an image that can be easily recognized and tracked.